# Handling @IBOutlet in UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to wrap a ViewController from one of Apple's demos in a SwiftUI UIViewControllerRepresentable, and it has a group of IBOutlets, which connect to the Main storyboard. How do I handle this situation? Should the IBOutlets be replaced with View structs, or should I try to incorporate the Storyboard along SwiftUI?

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ARView
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ARView {
        return ARView(model)
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController:
        ARViewContainer.UIViewControllerType, context:
        UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ARViewContainer>) { }
    
}

class ARView: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    // MARK: IBOutlets
    
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: VirtualObjectARView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addObjectButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var upperControlsView: UIView!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can definitely work, but you have to instantiate your `UIViewController` from the storyboard. Right now, you're just initializing it with `ARView()`, so it has no connection to the storyboard and no way to connect the outlets.

Basic example:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        MyStoryboardVCRepresented()
    }
}

struct MyStoryboardVCRepresented : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyStoryboardVC {
        UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(identifier: "MyVC") as! MyStoryboardVC //theoretically unsafe to unwrap like this with `!`, but we know it works, since the view controller is included in the storyboard
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyStoryboardVC, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.label.text = "Hello, world!"
    }
}

class MyStoryboardVC : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label : UILabel!
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Short and straight to the point